# Как правильно сериализовать указатель на целое с помощью boost?

Tags: c++, boost, сериализация

Мне необходимо сериализовать некий класс, в котором находятся нужные поля, которые задаются заданием. Я справился со всеми полями кроме одного - указателя на целое число. BOOST отказывается сериализовать его и выдает ошибки, хотя тот же указатель на экземпляр класса он сериализует нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно будет реализовать это?

```
class Person
{
 public:
    int age; // work
    int *ageptr = &age; // not work

    Person();
    ~Person();

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar &BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(age);
        ar &BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(ageptr); // error
    }
};
```

Comment: А есть вообще смысл сериализовать указатель? На то он и "указатель", что указывает на некий участок в памяти, а не на данные. Не факт, что при десереализации, ваш указатель будет оставаться валидным. Возможно проблема в этом?

Comment: @raviga, Да, смысла особо нет, но мне нужно это сделать. Скажем так, это одноразовая операция, десереализация не потребуется. Вот не знаю, как это провернуть

Comment: @VitaljaB. вы уверены, что поняли задание верно? Так как сериализация указателя не просто не имеет смысла, но даже вредна.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, да, я сам в замешательстве :)

Comment: Не получится сериализовать по указателью. Сериализовать указатель и нельзя и нелогично. Не пробовал, но не думаю, что стандарт это разрешит

Comment: @VitaljaB. у `boost.serialization` есть возможность сохранять данные по указателю, что позволяет сохранять и ресторить инфу с указателей на базовые классы (что реально круто) - возможно вам нужно это

Comment: если это одноразовая операция, то работайте с указателем как с беззнаковым целым (unsigned long), попахивает уб и смысл не ясен